# Issues debugging on Dr.java with a windows computer

Tags: java, debugging, drjava

I downloaded the latest version of dr.java - and also downloaded `jdk-14.01_windows-x64_bin.exe` and `jdk-14.01_windows-x64_bin.zip` I also tried using
`openjdk-8` and tried running dr.java.

Dr java is able to run and compile fine, but whenever I try to use the debugger I get the error described below.

I tried to change the path of the tools.jar to point to the jdk folder but that doesn't seem to be working. I couldn't find tools.jar. I'm using a Windows 10 with a 64-bit operating system.

```
java.lang.Error: no Connectors loaded
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.VirtualMachineManagerImpl.<init>(VirtualMachineManagerImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.VirtualMachineManagerImpl.virtualMachineManager(VirtualMachineManagerImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.jdi.Bootstrap.virtualMachineManager(Bootstrap.java:55)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.debug.jpda.JPDADebugger._getAttachingConnector(JPDADebugger.java:1034)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.debug.jpda.JPDADebugger._attachToVM(JPDADebugger.java:1008)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.debug.jpda.JPDADebugger.startUp(JPDADebugger.java:210)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.ui.MainFrame.debuggerToggle(MainFrame.java:4518)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.ui.MainFrame$129.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:2642)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:401)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:369)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1020)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1064)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2764)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)


System Properties:
DrJava Version drjava-20200303-210720
DrJava Build Time 20200303-210720

java.specification.version = 14
sun.cpu.isalist = amd64
sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
java.class.path = <anonymized user.home>\Downloads\drjava.jar
sun.awt.enableExtraMouseButtons = true
java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
sun.arch.data.model = 64
user.variant = 
java.vendor.url = https://java.oracle.com/
user.timezone = America/New_York
java.vm.specification.version = 14
os.name = Windows 10
sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
user.country = US
sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin
sun.java.command = <anonymized user.home>\Downloads\drjava.jar
drjava.debug.port = 50351
jdk.debug = release
sun.cpu.endian = little
user.home = <anonymized user.home>
user.language = en
java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.version.date = 2020-04-14
java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1
file.separator = \
java.vm.compressedOopsMode = 32-bit
line.separator = "\u000d\u000a"
java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
user.script = 
sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
java.runtime.version = 14.0.1+7
user.name = <anonymized user.name>
path.separator = ;
os.version = 10.0
java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
file.encoding = Cp1252
java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vendor.url.bug = https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/
java.io.tmpdir = <anonymized user.home>\AppData\Local\Temp\
java.version = 14.0.1
user.dir = <anonymized user.home>\Downloads
os.arch = amd64
java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
sun.os.patch.level = 
java.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;<anonymized user.home>\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;<anonymized user.home>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sophos\Sophos SSL VPN Client\bin;.
java.vm.info = mixed mode, sharing
java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version = 14.0.1+7
java.rmi.server.hostname = 127.0.0.1
sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
java.class.version = 58.0

DrJava configuration file
In resource bundle edu.rice.cs.drjava.config.options:
    nothing



Used memory: about 44.36 megabytes
Free memory: about 27.64 megabytes
Total memory: about 72 megabytes
Total memory can expand to: about 1.96 gigabytes

Number of processors/cores: 8

Compiler Discovery Log:
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow community! I'm really not familiar with DrJava, but are you sure that it does support JDK14, have you tried other versions of JDK, e.g. 1.8?

Comment: According to the official site of the DrJava, they say that "_The latest beta release of DrJava works transparently with OpenJDK 8 and OpenJRE 8 on all platforms_"

Comment: Hi, Thank you for getting back to me so quickly! I downloaded OpenJDK 8, and shut down Dr.Java and reloaded it. However the problem is still occurring. I think it may be that Dr. Java is not able to get access to the OpenJDK and I was wondering how to do that?

Comment: Okay, the tools.jar was removed in JDK9. Please check that you installed JDK8 correctly, and the windows PATH variable contains the path to it. E.g. I have this in PATH: _C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211_